# Input :) as text on slack

Tags: slack

I want to input `:)` as text in slack.

slack changes it to :slightly_smiling_face: automatically.

I tried using code block, (I can't show code block itself, so I use `` `)

```
`` `
:)
`` `
```

But I see only `:`. `)` was dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this approach but you have to edit the message once.

**Steps**

1. First type in `::):`
2. Then edit the message and remove extra colons `:` and you will only get `:)` in the message.

Other alternative can be just use `: )` instead of `:)` as suggested in another answer.

**Another way:**
Place your text in single tick (`)

```
`:)`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do `:)` and it wont screw up anything.